# Making an input value into a decimal

Tags: python, python-3.x, decimal

Currently I have this:

```
gpa = input("Enter your gpa: ")
gpa = int(gpa)
print("This is your current gpa:" , gpa)
```

How do I turn `gpa` into a decimal so it will print as a decimal?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
gpa = input("Enter your gpa: ")
gpa = int(gpa)
```

to

```
gpa = float(input("Enter your gpa: "))
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to convert to decimal use:

```
print("This is your current gpa:" , float(gpa))
```

if you want to display in some other format:

```
print("This is your current gpa:" , "%.2f" % gpa)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the float() function rather than int() function.

Answer (score 0):

```
gpa = float(input("Enter your gpa: "))
print("Your current gpa is %.2f " % gpa)
```

Comment: Please provide additional details instead of code only answers.